# how to connect raspbian strech over SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, debian-stretch

I just upgraded the ssd card to 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite. Hence, no screen, no keyboard, just headless. With the version before I used SSH to acess the raspberrypi 3. But now i have trouble. SSH is disabled by default. Could be overcome by writing an empty file named ssh into / . Fine, should be easy, but it isn't. I tried to mount the ssd-card in a card reader from a linux computer. This would allow to write the required empty file with cat /dev/null > /mnt/rasp/ssh , but it doesn't work, because the device is mounted read only indepent of how I try to mount for read-write!
Has anybody an Idea how to open the ssh, maybe over USB-Telnet, or what ever?

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a file called `ssh` in the `boot` partition, not the root partition.

You can also create a file called `wpa_supplicant` in the same place and your RasPi will join your wifi network.

You'll probably be able to `ssh` into it with:

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

If not, look in your router's *"DHCP clients"* table or use `nmap` to get its IP address. Or install the `fing` app in your smartphone and it'll tell you the IP addresses and host/OS of all your network clients.